# Get duplicates from list case insensitive

Tags: c#, linq, duplicates, string-comparison

```
List<string> testList = new List<string>();
testList.Add("A");
testList.Add("A");
testList.Add("C");
testList.Add("d");
testList.Add("D");
```

This query is case sensitive:

```
// Result: "A"
List<String> duplicates = testList.GroupBy(x => x)
                                  .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                                  .Select(g => g.Key)
                                  .ToList();
```

How would it look case insensitive? (Result: "A", "d")

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By using *overloaded implementation* of the `GroupBy` where you can provide the comparer required, e.g. `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`:

```
  var result = testList
    .GroupBy(item => item, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => g.Key)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

By replacing

```
.GroupBy(x => x)
```

with

```
.GroupBy(x => x.ToLower())
```

you turn all `string` elements to lower case and group case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = testList.GroupBy(x => x.ToLower())
                                  .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                                  .Select(g => g.Key)
                                  .ToList();
```